# Automatic content and structure extraction from web pages

Tags: web-scraping

I need to extract the top menu of webpages and the content area of webpages into an XML document, is there any tool which can do this for me?
The output of this should be the top menu structure of the website, that is its sitemap and the content of each page inside the main content area of the page.

Alternatively, if you cannot suggest an existing tool, could you suggest how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Automatic Web Data Extraction API](http://scrape.it) allows you to extract data automatically from a URL without writing any script.